# How to count in equal steps between two numbers in R?

Tags: r, sequence

Suppose we have two values: `100.0145` and `100.3325`. I want to count in 15 equal steps between these numbers and return those values. E.g. if we had `10` and `12` and I wanted to count in 1 step between these values, I would want `11` returning. Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: This is almost surely a duplicate but I think you are looking for `seq(100.0145, 100.3325, length.out=17)`.  The length of the output has to be 17 because it will include both 100.0145 and 100.3325.

Comment: Simple algebra works too:  `100.0145 + (1:15)*(100.3325 - 100.0145)/16`.  I'll drop a function of this as an answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple function to do it:

```
stepfun <- function(low, high, nsteps) {
    low + (1:nsteps) * (high - low) / (nsteps + 1)
}

stepfun(100.0145, 100.3325, 15)

#> 100.0344 100.0542 100.0741 100.0940 100.1139 100.1337 100.1536 100.1735 100.1934 100.2133 100.2331 100.2530 100.2729 100.2927 100.3126
```

A second function based on Amadou's answer in the comments:

```
stepfun2 <- function(low, high, nsteps) {
    x <- seq(low, high, length.out = nsteps + 2)
    x[-c(1, length(x))]
}

stepfun2(100.0145, 100.3325, 15)

#> 100.0344 100.0542 100.0741 100.0940 100.1139 100.1337 100.1536 100.1735 100.1934 100.2133 100.2331 100.2530 100.2729 100.2927 100.3126
```